# Base conversion

Tags: java, number-systems

I wrote a base conversion program. This base conversion should also work with base 1 (unary) where 000 is 3 and 0000000 is 7 and so on. It is only for non-negative numbers.

```
public class BaseConversion{
    private final static String alpha="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public static String ltob(long v, int base){
        if(base>alpha.length()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("base must not be greater than "+alpha.length());
        }
        if(base<=0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("base must not be lower than 0");
        }
        if(v<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input must not be lower than 0");
        }
        if(base==1){
            String ret="";
            while(v-->=0){
               ret+="0";
            }
            return ret;
        }
        String ret="";
        do{
            int x=(int)(v%((long)base));
            v/=base;
            ret=alpha.charAt(x)+ret;
        }while(v!=0);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "base must not be lower than 0" exception description is incorrect.  Better, "base must not be lower than **1**".  I also prefer to include the name of the method throwing the exception: "BaseConversion.ltob: base must not be lower than 1", but that is optional.

Comment: Your unary is wrong.  Unary 5 = 11111.  Every position in unary is 1^n = 1, so there as many 1s as the size of the number.  A minor change to your code.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         if(base==1){
>             String ret="";
>             while(v-->=0){
>                ret+="0";
>             }
>             return ret;
>         }
> ```

You should use a `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer`) rather than `String` concatenation.

```
        if (base == 1) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder((int)v);
            while (v-- >= 0) {
               result.append("0");
            }

            return result.toString();
        }
```

Note that this won't work if `v` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  You also shouldn't expect to be able to create a `String` that long.  I'll leave it up to you how you want to handle that situation.

There are a number of [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1802915/6660678) to do this.  This is just the closest to your original code.

Note:  I'm ignoring the question of the correct character to use in unary.  It's obviously trivial to change it to `1` here.

This should also be true for other bases, although it's harder to determine the correct string length.  Note that you can `append` each digit and then `reverse` the result at the end.

For bases up to hexatrigesimal (36), you can just use the built in `toString`.  I.e.

```
        return Long.toString(v, base);
```

Obviously your code handles additional situations that that won't.  For example, I don't think that handles unary.